# Probability that random point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ some distance away from origin

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $(X,Y)$ be a random point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and suppose that $X$ and $Y$ have independent $G(0,1)$ distributions (where $G(0,1)$ is the Gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1$). What is the probability that a point is less than $2$ units away from the origin?

I have no idea how to approach this problem. Would appreciate some hints/suggestions. Do we need to build a likelihood function?

Comment: What is $G(0,1)$?

Comment: Gaussian distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.

Comment: I have seen ${\cal N} (0,1)$ more frequently.

Comment: $\chi_2^2$. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks, will have to read about that.

Comment: The squared distance from the origin is $\mathsf{Chisq}(df=2)$ which is also an exponential distribution and easy to compute. The actual distance is a Rayleigh distribution. In R statistical software `pchisq(4,2)` returns 0.8646647.